# c# The connection was not closed, The connection's current state is open

Tags: c#, database

I'm trying to add my data into database and it worked however ever time it will display Exception message "The connection was not closed".
I already searched some solutions example

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
 //etc...
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Here is the code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connecting string");

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        //cmd.CommandText = " insert into Manipulate values('" + txtICNO.Text + "','" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtDisease.Text + "','" + txtContact.Text + "','" + txtHistory.Text + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "')";
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Manipulate (ICNO,Name,Disease,Contact,History,Address,Gender) values(@ICNO,@Name,@Disease,@Contact,@History,@Address,@Gender)";
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ICNO", txtICNO.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Disease", txtDisease.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", txtContact.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@History", txtHistory.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);

        if (rdbMale.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", "Male");
        else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", "Female");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        displayData();
        MessageBox.Show("record add successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the exception/error?

Comment: `using()` works and is the recommended way to safely dispose/close connections. Post the *actual* code and the full exception string, including its call stack. This will show where the exception actually occured. You can get this easily with `Exception.ToString()`. I'd guess your code either uses a global connection and forgets to close it properly, or `displayData()` tries to open a connection itself.

Comment: Is `displayData()` trying to use the same connection to refresh data after the INSERT statement? *Instead* of using the connection field, pass the connection as a parameter to `displayData`, ie `displayData(con)`. This way you avoid opening two connections to read the same thing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it worked....you are right.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I open connection for each function. Now I trying use your method avoid the problem

Answer (score 0):

You connection is opened somewhere else and closed in `btnAdd_Click`.
Also, is not known what happens in `displayData()`.
Move the new Connection declaration inside `btnAdd_Click` and enclose
all new object instances in {using} blocks.
Then, look what's inside `displayData()`.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try {
      using (var con = new SqlConnection("[Connection String]")) {
         con.Open();
         using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand()) {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Manipulate (ICNO,Name,Disease,Contact,History,Address,Gender) " + 
                              "values(@ICNO,@Name,@Disease,@Contact,@History,@Address,@Gender)";
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ICNO", txtICNO.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Disease", txtDisease.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", txtContact.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@History", txtHistory.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);

            if (rdbMale.Checked)
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", "Male");
            else
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", "Female");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            displayData();
            MessageBox.Show("record add successfully");
         }
      }
   }
   catch {
      // Notify, log, whatever
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add  condition like:

```
if(con.State==ConnectionState.Close)
{
    con.Open();
}
```

This will not reopen connection.